# C++ RegSetValueEx is giving problems

Tags: c++, registry

I'm using `RegSetValueEx` to set a Registry key. The problem is that it only writes the first 2 characters. I can get the `RegSetValueExA` (ANSI version) to work, but my Project is set to Unicode in properties so I  would like to use either `RegSetValueEx` or `RegSetValueExW`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Windows.h>

HKEY hKey;

int main()
{
    RegCreateKeyEx(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, L"SOFTWARE\\stuff", 0, NULL, NULL, KEY_ALL_ACCESS, NULL, &hKey, NULL);
    RegSetValueEx(hKey, L"Test", 0, REG_SZ, (const BYTE*)L"test", strlen("test"));

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Output in registry is `"te"` instead of `"test"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The final parameter to `RegSetValueEx` has to be the size in bytes of the value, including the terminating null. You're giving the length in characters (and each character needs two bytes) and not including the null.

`sizeof(L"test")` would work, I think, or you could use `(strlen("test")+1) * sizeof(wchar_t)`

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724923(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Either of those would work.  (I prefer sizeof(L"test") because it is the size of what is being passed in - but in practise, the value will be a variable so `(wstrlen(L"test")+1) * sizeof(wchar_t)` is probably a more useful base.

Comment: Thanks for the help :)